# JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've some DOM node:

```
<p>[CROP:1049,160x608,557x897] [CROP:1055,264x501,513x461] Some text</p>
```

I've created regular expression:

```
var re = new RegExp("\[CROP:(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+)\]", "ig");
```

But how can I get values from each `(\d)`?
As a result, I need to replace each `[CROP:xxx]` to `<a>` nodes like this:

```
<a href="#" class="myclass" data-id="1049" data-x1="160" data-x2="608" data-x3="557" data-x4="897">&nbsp;</a>
```

How can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this in 2 steps, I think there is no function to do this in one step:

1. match all the [CROP:...] blocks
2. match their inner parts

It would look like this:

```
function regex_func(pattern,text) {
    var i, max, sub = [],
        re = new RegExp(pattern, "ig"),
        match = text.match(re);
    if (match)
    {
        for (i=0, max=match.length; i<max; i++)
        {
            re = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
            sub[i] = re.exec(match[i]);    
        }
    }
    return sub;
}

var text = "[CROP:1049,160x608,557x897] [CROP:1055,264x501,513x461] Some text",
    pattern = "\\[CROP:(\\d+),(\\d+)x(\\d+),(\\d+)x(\\d+)\\]";
    matches = regex_func(pattern,text);

for (var i=0, max=matches.length; i<max; i++) {
    html = '<a href="#" class="myclass" data-id="'+matches[i][1]+'" data-x1="'+matches[i][2]+'" data-x2="'+matches[i][3]+'" data-x3="'+matches[i][4]+'" data-x4="'+matches[i][5]+'">'+matches[i][0]+'</a>';
    text = text.replace(matches[i][0],html);
}    

document.write(text);
```

You can text it here: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/fVQgp/5/

**Edit:** added the html string generation part, and the replace.

**Edit 2:** created a function to handle this matching problem. Used it in the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I replace these text strings to `<a>` DOM nodes?

Comment: You can create a HTML string and put that where ever you want in your page. (Modified my answer according.)

Comment: Yes, I've created new tag `<a>` with all attributes. But how can I replace each my `[CROP:xxx]` to corresponding `<a>`?

Comment: Sorry yes, added that too. It's just a simple substring replace on the original text.

Comment: Wait a sec, I created a function to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

From the ECMA spec:

> 15.10.6.2 RegExp.prototype.exec(string)
>   Performs a regular expression match of string against the regular expression and returns an Array object containing the results of the match, or null if string did not match.

e.g. match_data = re.exec(str)

Then match_data[1], ... will have each of the values within the parens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do var mymatch = re.exec("mystring"). The resulting variable will hold the text matched by the capturing parentheses.

EDIT: sorry, mymatch[0] contains the matched string, mymatch[1] the text matched by the first set of parenthses, etc.

Comment: So how does that work in his case where he has multiple captures?

Answer (score 0):

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++){
    var matches = paragraphs[p].innerHTML.match(/\[CROP:(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+)\]/ig);
    console.log('matches: ' + matches.length + ' found. (' + matches.join(';') + ')');
    for (var m = 0; m < matches.length; m++){
        var data = /\[CROP:(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+)\]/i.exec(matches[m]);
        console.log('data: ' + data + ' (' + data.length + ')');

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = '#';
        a.className = 'myclass';
        var attr = ['id','x1','x2','x3','x4'];
        for (var at = 0; at < attr.length; at++){
            a.setAttribute('data-'+attr[at],data[at+1]);
        }
        a.innerHTML = data.toString();

        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

Something like that? Use `<regex>.exec(<target>)` to get the matches, then you can use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=setAttribute) to append the data to the object.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sNhFa/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/Eb6b7/2/

I was unable to do this using a single RegEx, Here is the Javascript code from the link above:

```
var str = "[CROP:1,20x30,40x50] [CROP:9,8x00,400x500] [CROP:10,201x301,401x501] [CROP:100,21x31,41x51] some text";
var re1 = new RegExp(/\[CROP:(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+)\]/ig);
var re2 = new RegExp(/\[CROP:(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+),(\d+)x(\d+)\]/);
var data1 = str.match(re1);
var data2 = str.match(re2);

// Example of RegEx 1
for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++)
    $('#parsed_content1').append("<div>" +data1[i] + "</div>");

// Example of RegEx 2
for(var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++)
    $('#parsed_content2').append("<div>" +data2[i] + "</div>");

// What you are looking for
for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
    var data3 = data1[i].match(re2);
    for(var j = 0; j < data3.length; j++)
    $('#overall').append("<div>" +data3[j] + "</div>");

}
```